# How do I provide my own FQDN for my hostnames?

Tags: azure

I am searching the documentation on how I can provide my own FQDN to my hosts in Azure but don't seem to find what I need. How are you all setting your FQDN so that you can access your different host systems by that name instead of *name*.cloudapp.net

I essentially want to access it by machine.domain.tld (where domain.tld is my own domain name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably the support documentation regarding DNS Services and configuration of Azure Cloud services.

**Microsoft Azure Support Pointers**

I found a support article on the [configuration of a custom domain name](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) for an Azure Cloud Service.

I am not sure if you are asking about [configuring DNS for a Web Site service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/), which looks like it has different instructions so choose appropriately.

**Make Changes with Your Domain Registrar**

Depending on whom you have registered your domain name with, you will need to set up a `DNS A Record` and a `DNS CNAME` to get what you need.

The "A Record" is where the domain.tld value is assigned.  It will be the same as your cloud service public-ip.  The `machine` name represented in your assigned DNS address is associated with a Domain C-Name record established with your Domain name Registrar and pointed to your A Record.

Follow the instructions to also configure your cloud service settings.  Pointing the domain name to your cloud service will not be enough.